# Error in using match.arg for multiple arguments

Tags: r, function, match, apply

I am new to using `match.arg` for default value specification in R functions. And I have a query regarding the below behavior.

```
trial_func <- function(a=c("1","9","20"),b=c("12","3"),d=c("55","01")){
  a <- match.arg(a)
  b <- match.arg(b)
  d <- match.arg(d)
  list(a,b,d)
}
trial_func()
# [[1]]
# [1] "1"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "12"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "55"
```

When I try using `match.arg` for each individual argument, it works as expected. But when I try to use an lapply to reduce the code written, it causes the below issue.

```
trial_func_apply <- function(a=c("1","9","20"),b=c("12","3"),d=c("55","01")){
  lapply(list(a,b,d), match.arg)
}
trial_func_apply()
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 'arg' must be of length 1

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After investigating a bit, you need to pass the argument that your character vector is NULL, i.e.

```
trial_func_apply <- function(a=c("1","9","20"),b=c("12","3"),d=c("55","01")){
     lapply(list(a,b,d), function(i)match.arg(NULL, i))
 }

trial_func_apply()
#[[1]]
#[1] "1"

#[[2]]
#[1] "12"

#[[3]]
#[1] "55"
```

Comment: It seems that your `a`, `b`, `c` represent the `choices` argument of the function rather than `arg`. Other than that, I am not familiar with this function so can't say for sure

Comment: This answer is wrong, because `match.arg` as it is used here will not complain if the given values are invalid (e.g `trial_func_apply(a="222222")` does not give an error with this code)

Comment: This answer follows the OP way of doing it. It is the same function as the OP constructed but written correctly

Comment: Sorry, I have to disagree. Your implementation is not equivalent to the original `trial_func` given by the OP. For instance, when you run `trial_func(a="222222")` you get an error because "222222" is not a valid choice. With your solution you don't get that error.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but I feel it's a great one, so I will try to provide extensive explanation for it by explaining the following:

- Read the relevant documentation for `?match.arg`
- Make `match.arg` fail to guess the choices
- Learn three features of the R language that `match.arg` uses underneath.
- Simplified `match.arg` implementation
- Make the `lapply` example of the question work

### `match.arg` documentation

The usage tells you that `match.arg` needs the selected option you want to match (`arg`) and all the possible `choices`:

```
match.arg(arg, choices, several.ok = FALSE)
```

If we read `choices`, we see that it can often be missing, and we should read more in the details... How could `match.arg` work without having the possible choices, we wonder?

> choices: a character vector of candidate values, often missing, see
> ‘Details’.

Maybe the Details section gives some hints (bold is mine):

> Details:
>
> **In the one-argument form ‘match.arg(arg)’, the choices are
> obtained from a default setting for the formal argument ‘arg’ of
> the function from which ‘match.arg’ was called.**  (Since default
> argument matching will set ‘arg’ to ‘choices’, this is allowed as
> an exception to the ‘length one unless ‘several.ok’ is ‘TRUE’’
> rule, and returns the first element.)

So, if you don't specify the `choices` argument, R will make a bit of effort to guess it right automagically. For the R magic to work, several conditions must be fulfilled:

1. The `match.arg` function must be called directly from the function with the argument
2. The name of the variable to be matched must be the name of the argument.

### `match.arg()` can be tricked:

Let's make `match.arg()` fail to guess the choices:

```r
dummy_fun1 <- function(x = c("a", "b"), y = "c") {
  # If you name your argument like another argument
  y <- x
  # The guessed choices will correspond to y (how could it know they were x?)
  wrong_choices <- match.arg(y)
}

dummy_fun1(x = "a")
# Error in match.arg(y) : 'arg' should be “c”

dummy_fun2 <- function(x = c("a", "b"), y = "c") {
  # If you name your argument differently
  z <- x
  # You don't get any guess:
  wrong_choices <- match.arg(z)
}

dummy_fun2(x="a")
#Error in match.arg(z) : 'arg' should be one of
```

### Three R language features that match.arg needs and uses

(1) It uses non-standard evaluation to get the name of the variable:

```
whats_the_var_name_called <- function(arg) {
  as.character(substitute(arg))
}

x <- 3
whats_the_var_name_called(x)
# "x"
y <- x
whats_the_var_name_called(y)
# "y"
```

(2) It uses `sys.function()` to get the caller function:

```
this_function_returns_its_caller <- function() {  
  sys.function(1)
}

this_function_returns_itself <- function() {
  me <- this_function_returns_its_caller()
  message("This is the body of this_function_returns_itself")
  me
}

> this_function_returns_itself()
This is the body of this_function_returns_itself
function() {
  me <- this_function_returns_its_caller()
  message("This is the body of this_function_returns_itself")
  me
}
```

(3) It uses `formals()` to get the possible values:

```
a_function_with_default_values <- function(x=c("a", "b"), y = 3) {

}

formals(a_function_with_default_values)[["x"]]
#c("a", "b")
```

### How does `match.arg` work?

Combining these things, `match.arg` uses `substitute()` to get the name of the args variable, it uses `sys.function()` to get the caller function, and it uses `formals()` on the caller function with the argument name to get the default values of the function (the choices):

```
get_choices <- function(arg, choices) {
  if (missing(choices)) {
    arg_name <- as.character(substitute(arg))
    caller_fun <- sys.function(1)
    choices_as_call <- formals(caller_fun)[[arg_name]]
    choices <- eval(choices_as_call)
  }
  choices
}

dummy_fun3 <- function(x = c("a", "b"), y = "c") {
  get_choices(x)
}
dummy_fun3()
#[1] "a" "b"
```

Since we now know the magic used to get the choices, so we can create our `match.arg` implementation:

```r
my_match_arg <- function(arg, choices) {
  if (missing(choices)) {
    arg_name <- as.character(substitute(arg))
    caller_fun <- sys.function(1)
    choices_as_call <- formals(caller_fun)[[arg_name]]
    choices <- eval(choices_as_call)
  }
  # Really simple and cutting corners... but you get the idea:
  arg <- arg[1]
  if (! arg %in% choices) {
    stop("Wrong choice")
  }
  arg
}

dummy_fun4 <- function(x = c("a", "b"), y = "c") { 
  my_match_arg(x)
}

dummy_fun4(x="d")
# Error in my_match_arg(x) : Wrong choice
dummy_fun4(x="a")
# [1] "a"
```

And that's how `match.arg` works.

### Why it does not work under `lapply`? How to fix it?

To guess the `choices` argument, we look at the caller argument. When we use `match.arg()` inside an lapply call, the caller is not our function, so `match.arg` fails to guess the `choices`.  We can get the choices manually and provide the choices manually:

```
trial_func_apply <- function(a=c("1","9","20"),b=c("12","3"),d=c("55","01")){
  this_func <- sys.function()
  the_args <- formals(this_func)
  default_choices <- list(
    eval(the_args[["a"]]),
    eval(the_args[["b"]]),
    eval(the_args[["d"]])
  )
  # mapply instead of lapply because we have two lists we
  # want to apply match.arg to
  mapply(match.arg, list(a,b,d), default_choices)
}
trial_func_apply()
# [1] "1"  "12" "55"
```

Please note that I am cutting corners by not defining the environments where all the evals should happen, because in the examples above they work as-is. There may be some corner cases that make this examples to fail, so don't use them in production.